# Examples of using Dream spell in official material

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, lore, books

The [*Dream* spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dream) gained a *lot* of power in 5th edition, and while perhaps a bit "meh" at a first glance, on a second thought it seems incredibly powerful for a mere 5th level spell (so needs 9th level caster). As I have this spell for a character I am playing, I want to learn more about the lore surrounding the spell.

**Is there any published, official(ish) material which makes use of the *Dream* spell of 5th edition?**

Adventures, campaign/setting books, rule books or plain fiction novels, anything like that counts. If it has been given the permission to use the **Dungeons&Dragons** logo on the cover, it is official enough. Published as PDF only is ok, as long as it is available for download/purchase.

Note: if there is something in some adventure, please use the appropriate spoiler markup for details.

I don't think there are many cases, so I hope this isn't too broad a question. I'm just hoping there is at least *something*.

Comment: I think the question seeks to find concrete examples of the spells power. What it is capable of doing or not doing, beyond the language of the spell itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Dream spell is used in Rise of Tiamat adventure

> In the later part of the adventure, during Chapter 16, characters travel to Thay.
>  The Red Wizards are suspicious of the characters' motives and so they are subjected to the Dream spell in the night.
>  In the Dream they are presented with a torturous nightmare scenario and interrogated about their motives by the Red Wizards. The Red Wizards then use the information gained this way later in the adventure.

### The Dream spell is also used in Princes of the Apocalypse adventure

> In Chapter 4 characters are destroying shrines of Elemental Evil. After several of the shrines are destroyed, a cult uses the Dream spell to contact a party member and issue a threat to a nearby town they plan to destroy as a punishment for the sacrilege.

Those are the only two instances I managed to find, but there might be others. It seems and it would make sense that the spell is used as a more powerful version of something like sending where the user of the spell is in control and can pressure the target while staying in control of the situation.